# Why is there a difference in execution time while running the same program multiple times?

Tags: c, linux, time, operating-system

Probably a dumb question. I'm noticing a difference in execution time while running a simple `Hello World` program in `C` on a Linux machine( It's not language specific though).

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();

    printf("%s", "Hello World\n");
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f\n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

o/p:

```
$ ./hello 
Hello World
0.000061
$ ./hello 
Hello World
0.000057
$ ./hello 
Hello World
0.000099
```

This is tested on a quad core machine with a load average of 0.4 and enough free memory. Though the difference is pretty small, what could be the reason behind it?

Comment: The run-time of the program is waaay too short, thus the deviations are mostly due the "rounding" error.

Comment: Aside: you should probably change `"\n%s"` to `"%s\n"` since your message may not have been output before `end = clock();`

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're running a real-time operating system, you're going to see at least a slight variation in run times.  This is due to OS scheduling, any I/O that might be happening at around that time, etc.

A difference of 0.04 ms is not a big difference at all.

If your program runs in a loop for at least several seconds, the percentage of variation should be reduced.

Comment: Mean if I want to check time interval in any RTOS, it will always equal to almost actual time no matter how many time I run the program or how many context switches etc. happens between processes?

Comment: @Mazhar In a real time OS, there shouldn't *be* any context switches.  That's what guarantees the runtime of the program in question.  There could still be variation, such as the program in question communicating with various I/O devices, but no external variation.

Comment: @dbush: "In a real time OS, there shouldn't be any context switches" - Wrong. A RTOS guarantees a deterministic latency behaviour, but not none at all. Nor does it not have context switches in general (there are some implementations which don't have). And if your application violates constraints, the timing-behaviour is not deterministic anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is: what is happening in the rest of the system.

There are all of these background processes that do 'stuff': process network packets; save or log data to the disk; decide to wake up and check the current network time; who knows! For such a short time interval as your code, those tiny things can make a large difference. Try doing the loop 1,000 times and checking those results. Of course, output to the screen involves graphics, updates, other programs... maybe you should just do a:

```
unsigned i, j;
...
// Wait a LONG time!
for (i=0;i<5u;++i) { // 5 is about a minute on my machine
    for (j=0;j<~0u;++j) {
        // Twiddle thumbs!
    } // for
} // for
```

inside your timing.

Answer (score 0):

Two major causes:

1. Disk caching: Once your executable is loaded the first time, it may remain in memory so that the the subsequent runs do not require a fetch from disk.
2. System activity: What else is your processor doing at the same time that are consuming resources (memory, CPU, disk access).